# Selected option not working on select dropdown in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am getting some strange behavior on my Dropdown control in Angular Js application. Now selected="selected" is not working and default selected values are blank.

I have also been facing another issue on the edit click button. It is associated to gender and should be selected automatically on dropdown but it is still not working.

```
<select ng-model="newemployee.Gender" class="form-control">
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Male</option>
   <option value="0">Female</option>
</select>
```

Is it due to Angular.js file which I have updated to latest version? Because such issues arose after updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had problems with the selected options sometimes and what I use to do is using `ng-selected` like this:

```
<option value="1" ng-selected="newemployee.Gender == '1'">Male</option>
```

So the option will be selected if both values are equal. You can find more information here: [ng-selected Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

Comment: Are you initialising the value of newempoyee.Gender?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize newemployee.Gender to 1 instead

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue and tried a lot finally this worked for me

```
<select ng-model="newemployee.Gender" class="form-control">
   <option value="1" ng-selected="newemployee.Gender = '1'">Male</option>
   <option value="0">Female</option>
</select>
```